# Eclipse silently crashing after importing projects, executing jUnit tests, etc

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, crash

Eclipse crashes every time I import a project from the workspace, or when I execute jUnit tests. .log gives no info on the crash, it just silently quits with no messages.

Currently using Eclipse 3.8, but this occurs with all the other versions of Eclipse I have tried (including Luna) on this Lenovo ThinkPad running Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit). Running java 1.7. and updated adb to latest.

I have also added    `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` to the eclipse.ini - any help?

```
!SESSION 2014-11-04 16:17:53.738 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 2 0 2014-11-04 16:17:58.126
!MESSAGE No search provider was registed. Tasks search is not available.
!SESSION 2014-11-04 16:19:44.042 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 2 0 2014-11-04 16:19:47.069
!MESSAGE No search provider was registed. Tasks search is not available.
!SESSION 2014-11-04 16:22:33.202 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 2 0 2014-11-04 16:22:35.782
!MESSAGE No search provider was registed. Tasks search is not available.
!SESSION 2014-11-04 16:28:54.839 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 2 0 2014-11-04 16:28:57.871
!MESSAGE No search provider was registed. Tasks search is not available.
!SESSION 2014-11-04 16:35:29.208 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-11-04 16:35:30.567
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 2 0 2014-11-04 16:35:32.051
!MESSAGE No search provider was registed. Tasks search is not available.
!SESSION 2014-11-04 16:52:37.089 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 2 0 2014-11-04 16:52:39.672
!MESSAGE No search provider was registed. Tasks search is not available.
!SESSION 2014-11-04 17:02:53.792 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 2 0 2014-11-04 17:02:56.183
!MESSAGE No search provider was registed. Tasks search is not available.
!SESSION 2014-11-04 17:03:53.709 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 2 0 2014-11-04 17:03:56.173
!MESSAGE No search provider was registed. Tasks search is not available.
```

Comment: start from the command line and see if you get any output on crash there

Comment: thank you, this got me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

got the logs after running it from the command line, per the suggestion above. there was a reference to g_object_get_qdata, which seems to be a GTK2 theme conflict. need to run Eclipse with a different GTK2 theme (like Raleigh):

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /usr/bin/eclipse
```

works fine with this workaround.

see defect: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1205452